# Limit+equations

Tags: limits

Find $a$ and $b$ such that below function be continuous:
$$
f(x) =  \begin{cases}
{a{x^2} + bx + 1}&\left| x \right| \ge 1
\\
{2ax + b[x] + c{{( - 1)}^{[x]}}}&{\left| x \right| < 1}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: As both branches make a definition for $|x|=1$, this does not even define a function unless both branches coincide at $\pm1$. Ansd shouldn't we find $a$, $b$, and also $c$?

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: problem is edited!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f(0)=c$ and $f(x)=2ax-b-c$ for $-1<x<0$, so for continuity at $0$ we need $c=-b-c$, i.e. $$\tag1c=-\frac12b.$$ Then $f(x)=2ax-\frac12b$ for $-1\le x<1$ (as $[\cdot]$ has no other places of dicontinuity in $(-1,1)$).
Thus $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=2a-\frac12b$ and $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=a+b+1$, so we need $$\tag22a-\frac12b=a+b+1.$$
Also, $\lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)=-2a-\frac12b$ and $\lim_{x\to-1^-}f(x)=a-b+1$, so we need $$\tag3-2a-\frac12b=a-b+1.$$
From $(2)$ and $(3)$ you should find $a=-\frac12$, $b=-1$ and then from $(1)$ $c=\frac12$.